# Problem uploading file to onedrive c# core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm actually tring to create an app where user can upload files on the server and each day, there is a program which get all files uploaded to go upload them in onedrive other user.
But at some point i'm getting an unexpected error when trying to upload and i can't find any clue on how i can resolve it since the log isn't telling me that much.

You can find the code below, and every hint to help me find the issue would be great since i'm new on the api.
I gave on azure all the rights to the application since i want to application be able to use the api without signin.

Thx !

The code i'm using to connect to the graph api microsoft :

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientId)
            .WithTenantId(TenantID)
            .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
        return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

And to upload :

```
                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);

                using (fileStream)
                {
                var uploadedFile = graphClient.Users[email].Drive.Root
                        .ItemWithPath(path)
                        .Content
                        .Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream).Result;                    
            }
```

The error in the catch i'm getting :
One or more errors occurred. (Code: generalException
Message: An unspecified error has occurred.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2021-01-29T08:43:32
request-id: 56f92a21-f7ed-407d-8832-1d37f909c46d
client-request-id: 56f92a21-f7ed-407d-8832-1d37f909c46d
ClientRequestId: 56f92a21-f7ed-407d-8832-1d37f909c46d
)

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple demo for you,just try console app code below：

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace OneDriveUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientID = "<app id>";
            var clientSec = "<app secret>";
            var tenant = "<tenent id/name>";
            var userID = "<user id/upn>";

            var filePath = @"<local file path>\uploadDemo.txt";
            var fileName = "uploadDemo.txt";

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientID)
                .WithTenantId(tenant)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSec)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
             var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath);
            
            var uploadedFile = graphClient.Users[userID].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(reader.BaseStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine(uploadedFile.Size);

           
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions that granted to app:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to upload large files, see [this official demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp).

Comment: hmm i tried but it still doesn't work. Only working when i use my own userid but doesn't work on other...:/

Comment: @MeganeNiama, any exception information ? And please make sure that your other accounts has configed office365 correctly and  been assigned licenses correctly

Comment: just got this when i tried in console app :
'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' dans System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Code: generalException
Message: An unspecified error has occurred.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2021-02-04T08:04:14
 request-id: 5c743b36-9500-49d9-9234-6c7b7a62f4d2
 client-request-id: 5c743b36-9500-49d9-9234-6c7b7a62f4d2
ClientRequestId: 5c743b36-9500-49d9-9234-6c7b7a62f4d2